# How to do string.format() from python in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to learn C++. I have a little bit of python in my background. Is there anyway to do the string formatting in C++ just like I did in python using format?

class Employee{
    public:
        int pay;
        string Lname;
        string Fname;
        string email;

```
    Employee(int apay, string aLname, string aFname){
        pay = apay;
        Fname = aFname;
        Lname = aLname;
        email = "%s.%s@gmail.com", aFname, aLname;

    // in python i could do email = "{}.{}@gmail.com".format(aFname, aLname)
```

I expect the output of `cout << emp1.email;` to be first.last@gmail.com.

Comment: sorry if im asking dumb questions. im new to programming.

Comment: Completely valid @mjarosie as the question even though it has the same answer is on itself a different question which helps those who google

Comment: What you want is C++20s format library: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r9.html. the reference implementation can be found at https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> std::operator+ (string)

like this `email = aFname+"."+ aLname+"@gmail.com";`

check this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) for more informations.